# Creating a lookup table in a microcontroller using in C

Tags: microcontroller, pic, c

How can I create a lookup table in a microcontroller using C? I have one input and one output and want to implement a lookup table in C.

Answer (score 14):

I'll give a general answer since the question lacks information:

Suppose you have an `uint8_t` as input and a `uint8_t` as output and you want to create a full lookup table (i.e. every input has an output). You'd need 256 values, as the input can have 256 different values.  You can now create a table with:

```
const uint8_t the_table[256] = { ... }
```

The `const` keyword is to store the table in the flash memory, not in the RAM. This is because RAM is scarce in microcontrollers, as jippie points out in the comments.

In the curly brackets, the values should go. You can now easily lookup an input value with `the_table[input_value]`.

---

Generally, we could say a lookup table would look as follows:

```
const OutputType the_table[CountOfInputValues] = { ... };
```

---

A small example for a lookup table to do this conversion (from the [Gray code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code), [thanks to Anindo Ghosh](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9260279#9260279)):

```
input -> output
0b000    0b000
0b001    0b001
0b010    0b011
0b011    0b010
0b100    0b110
0b101    0b111
0b110    0b101
0b111    0b100
```

Might be implemented as follows, using `uint8_t`, or a byte, as the output type:

```
const uint8_t gray_code[8] = {0b000, 0b001, 0b011, 0b010, 0b110, 0b111, 0b101, 0b100};
```

You can lookup a value with:

```
some_var = gray_code[input];
```

Comment: I like this explanation clear and simple :).

Comment: `uint32_t gray( uint32_t number ) { return number ^= ( number >> 1 ); }` Don't need a table for that.

Comment: On an ARM processor that takes only 1 clock cycle! `EOR Rn,Rn,Rn,LSR 1`, no way a lookup table can beat that.

Comment: This will store the lookup table in RAM, which is scarce in most microcontrollers. Change it into `const char gray_code[8] = {0b0.....` to store the table in flash. Another possibilty is the use of the `#ROM` Directive, but I am unsure how to use make the compiler assign a block of unused flash memory.

Comment: While it's *usually* desirable to avoid having constant initializers copied from flash to limited ram on startup (thus proper use of "const" and pragmas or linker configuration), there is an exception:  many of these processors are comparably slow at fetching data from flash "program" memory, so if there is RAM available for it, a table in RAM initialized only once from the flash at startup may be faster.

Comment: Thanks Chris, let us say I have one sensor which has one input of temp. and output of resistance. It is given in table and I want to present that table in  pic microcontroller  in MPLAB. So how i can create a look up table.Pls. guide me.  Thanks

Comment: @PrabinKumar a) why didn't you give this information from the start and b) why don't you follow my answer for a how-to?

Comment: Do you have any simple example like this? please share with me.

Comment: I am a just beginner in this field.

Comment: @PrabinKumar I cannot give you that without you providing the table. Have a look at the gray code example in my answer. It shows you how to generate the code from the table. You can do the same with your values. If you're still in doubt after that, please edit your question to add the table you want. _Without the values, it's impossible to give you a working code._

Comment: @PrabinKumar I'm sorry, but your responses come across as [tag:send-me-teh-codez]. Perhaps if you demonstrated effort in working with the guidelines provided, and came back with any specific issues you could not resolve, you would get the help you actually need.

Answer (score 5):

Here's an example of how I would create a lookup table for some precomputed values.  I will use an example of swapping bits front-to-back within a byte.  This is sometimes useful for FFT algorithms or SPI peripherals that want the wrong order.

First I create a program that creates the table.  Maintaining the table by hand is drudgery and error-prone, so this job should be given to the computer.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

def swapbits(x):
    ret=0
    for i in range(8):
        if x&(1<<i): ret |= 1<<(7-i)
    return ret

print "const uint8_t bitswap[] = {",
print ", ".join("0x%02x"%swapbits(x) for x in range(256)),
print "}"
```

I call this file "bitend.py".   Notice I used a scripting language instead of a C program for this.  Generating the table is fundamentally a string-processing problem, and C is a pain to do string processing in.  Because the table is only needed at compile-time, I can use a caveman-simple algorithm that is more obviously correct than an optimized one.

Now to integrate this into the build.  In my Makefile, I put a section like this:

```
generated_swapbits.c: bitend.py
       echo "/* generated by bitend.py, do not edit */" > generated_swapbits.c
       python bitend.py >> generated_swapbits.c
```

Here I made a dependency on the python script, so that if I edit the script, the C file will be regenerated automatically.

In my main C code, I just include the generated file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "generated_swapbits.c"

int main(void) { 
   printf("Swapped 0x0f is %0x\n", swapbits[0x0f]); 
}
```

Now in my Makefile, I have to include the generated file as a dependency of the C code:

```
a.out: main.c generated_swapbits.c
     $(CC) $(CFLAGS) main.c
```

And the last thing is to add "generated_swapbits.c" to the Makefile's "clean" target, so the file will be removed upon "make clean".

If you use an IDE instead of make, you will need to consult its documentation about running scripts to satisfy dependencies.  (If the IDE doesn't support this, choose a different IDE.)